# Splitting a string into two halfs

Tags: java, arrays, string, split, binary

I am making a new conversion software to hide messages (for fun). I have made a Binary and Decimal conversion class and my idea is, a user inputs string, it converts all to Binary format. Then splits it in half, converts one half to decimal, then adds the string back together again to make it a mix of binary and decimal. In other versions I will add more conversions, more splits,and maybe convert to languages too. I need splitting the string in half. This is my code so far::

```
public ray() {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Please input the text you wish to encode!");
        System.out.println("Type '#' to quit the Software.");
        String s1 = in.nextLine();
        if ("#".equalsIgnoreCase(s1)) {
            System.out.println("Goodbye, hope you enjoyed RAYConversion v1.0 Alpha.");
            // close software
        }

        // convert all to binary
        binary Binary = new binary();

        //what i need to do is split stirng s1 in half, make it into different strings. Then I will convert
        //the two strings to binary and decimal. I made a converter for that.

    }
}
```

Comment: How do you split the String "AAA" in half?

Comment: Please use naming conventions. A class called `ray` should be called `Ray`, and `binary Binary` should be `Binary binary` - with a class `Binary` and a variable `binary`. Also, what is the upper/lower case of `'#'`, considering you are calling `equalsIgnoreCase()` on a `String` with only that character?

Comment: I am kinda new to Java, It works for me, equalsIgnoreCase could be equals I know, I am used to using Bukkit API lol, where i use equalsIgnoreCase for commands. And AAA, the second half would have AA and first would have A.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
final int mid = s1.length() / 2; //get the middle of the String
String[] parts = {s1.substring(0, mid),s1.substring(mid)};
System.out.println(parts[0]); //first part
System.out.println(parts[1]); //second part
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Java's substring function to divide them in halves:

```
String s1a = s1.substring(0, (s1.length()/2));
String s1b = s1.substring((s1.length()/2);
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this will get you done what you want to achieve:

P.S. Note that for Strings with `odd` number of characters, the second-half String will get the benefit of the extra character.

Create a method like this:

```
public static String substring(int a, int b, String temp) {
    String a = "";
    for(int i = a; i<b; i++) {
        char ch1 = temp.charAt(i);
        a = a + ch1;
    }
    return a;
}
```

and in your `main` function, call the method as below:

```
String s1a = substring(0, (s1.length()/2), s1);
String s1b = substring((s1.length()/2),s1.length(), s1);
```

Comment: very helpful, ty! However am probably going to use the other as it makes much more sense and is smaller in code. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Edited and Improved my answer. I guess this makes it much simpler and even easier for you to understand what happens in the function.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int len = whole.length();
String a = whole.substring(0, len / 2), b = whole.substring(len / 2);
```

This uses the [`substring()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-) method. In the case of a `String` with odd length, the second half will be one character longer.

Answer (score 0):

This method drops the middle character of the Strings having odd lengths. This is done by the `2 + 1` in the second half in the else part.

```
public void method()
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("ENTER A STRING");
    original = sc.next();
    
    if(original.length()%2 == 0)
    {
        firsthalf =original.substring(0, original.length()/2);
        secondhalf = original.substring(original.length()/2);
        System.out.println(firsthalf);
        System.out.println(secondhalf);
    }
    else
    {
        firsthalf = original.substring(0, original.length()/2);
        secondhalf = original.substring(original.length()/2+1);
        System.out.println(firsthalf);
        System.out.println(secondhalf);
    }   
}
```

Comment: This method drops the middle character of the string having odd length. This is done by the "2+1" in the secondhalf in the else part. Hope you find it useful.

Comment: Not sure if OP wants to drop the middle character