# How to split a string into two equally based on the its length

Tags: java

I need to split a string based on the length. IF the length of string is `700` i want to split the string into two with equal length 350 each . How could i split this .

```
String text;
int length = text.length();
```

Comment: Use String.substring(int start_index).

Comment: [`String#substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-)

Comment: What would you expect if the string have 699 characters?

Comment: first 350 characters in one string and others in second string

Comment: whoops...@Phi beat me to it :) - Deleting my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the commenting privilege yet, but this is a duplicate. This question could be found from a quick Google: [Splitting a string into two halfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32423346/splitting-a-string-into-two-halfs)

```
int mid = length / 2; //get the middle of the String
String[] parts = {text.substring(0, mid),text.substring(mid)};
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is what you need:

```
String firsthalf = text.subString(0,length/2);
String secondhalf = text.subString(length/2,length);
```

Answer (score 1):

First you get the length of the `String`, then get `subString` from that string

```
String string = "Hello World";

int length = string.length();

String firstPart = string.subString(0,length/2);
String secondPart = string.subString(length/2,length);
```

That's it.